# Removing all rows in dataframe with "$-" in one of the columns

Tags: r

I have an a dataframe that contains a column with dollar amounts. I need to drop all rows that contain a "$-" in that column.

I have tried changing the column to a factor, replacing the "$-" to NA and 0's. All of the codes I have used have either done nothing or dropped all the values.

```
df$bal<- sub("$-","",df$bal)
is.na_remove <- df$bal[!is.na(df$bal)]
df[df==""]<-0
df$bal<- lapply(list, function(df) df[df$bal=="$-"])
df$bal<- gsub("$-","",df$bal)
```

I want all of those rows to drop, Ill be willing to remove the $ from the entire column and then dropping.

Comment: Welcome! It would help to provide a **small**, reproducible example of your data frame. Use the function `dput()` to write a text representation of your data.

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without seeing any of your data, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36344180/5325862) is one of several SO posts dealing with something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is to remove the rows, a better option would be `grep` to find the substring "$-" in the 'bal' column.

```
out <- df[!grepl("$-", df$bal, fixed = TRUE), ]
```

Note that by default, the `sub/gsub/grep` etc matches with regular expressions as `fixed = FALSE` and in regex, some characters have special meaning for matching.  One of this is `$` which suggests the end of the string.  If we don't specify `fixed = TRUE` or escape (`\\$`), it evaluates `$` as the end of string instead of the literal character